# Flip text within textPath element of an SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

I've been having a huge problem here. There is some text within a textPath tag of an svg element that I need to flip 180 degrees. I've used all methods that would work with css but absolutely NOTHING works. Can anyone help me with flipping the text within the element.

```js
function Init() {
  let w = wrap.clientWidth;
  let h = wrap.clientHeight;
  ellipse.setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", `0 0 ${w}  ${h}`);
  let d = `M${w / 10},${h / 2}A${4 * w / 10},${4 * h / 10} 0 0 0 ${9 *
    w /
    10} ${5 * h / 10} A${4 * w / 10},${4 * h / 10} 0 0 0 ${w / 10} ${5 *
    h /
    10} A${4 * w / 10},${4 * h / 10} 0 0 0 ${9 * w / 10} ${5 * h / 10} A${4 *
    w /
    10},${4 * h / 10} 0 0 0 ${w / 10} ${5 * h / 10}`;

  thePath.setAttributeNS(null, "d", d);
  let path_length =  thePath.getTotalLength();
  
  
  //begin at a bigger size than needed
  let font_size = 100;
  ellipse.style.fontSize = font_size+"px"; 
  
  // while the text length is bigger than half path length 
  while(tp.getComputedTextLength() > path_length / 2 ){
    //reduce the font size
    font_size -=.25;
    //reset the font size 
    ellipse.style.fontSize = font_size+"px";
  }
}



window.setTimeout(function() {
  Init();
  window.addEventListener("resize", Init, false);
}, 15);

let so = 0;

function Marquee() {
  requestAnimationFrame(Marquee);
  tp.setAttributeNS(null, "startOffset", so + "%");
  if (so >= 50) {
    so = 0;
  }
  so += 0.02;
}

Marquee();
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: "Arimo", sans-serif;
}

#wrap{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;  
}
text {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: lighter;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <svg id="ellipse" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
    <path id="thePath" fill="transparent" d="M100,500A400,400 0 0 0 900 500 A400,400 0 0 0 100 500"  />

       <text stroke="black">
          <textPath xlink:href="#thePath" dy="5" id="tp" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs">Coming Soon • Coming Soon • Coming Soon • Coming Soon • Coming Soon • Coming Soon • Coming Soon •</textPath>
        </text>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: please edit your question and add the code you have. Probably you may need to reverse the path but  need to see the code

Comment: alright ill send you the code pen here:

Comment: https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/161bb8a12afab3628f55425050bb5048

Comment: the thing is that I need the text to be going in the same direction its already going(anti-clockwise)

Comment: Add the code to a snippet in the question please. Also, CSS transforms should work, but keep in mind that SVG elemts also need their transform-box and transform-origin set or all transforms will align to the viewport instead of the element.

Comment: Ive tried adding the code but the website does not alllow me to as it says it has errors. Sorry about this hick-up, Im new to Stack Overflow and really need help with this little problem

Comment: I basically need the bottom text to look like the top part and the top to look like the bottom while the svg still rotates in the same direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've commented you need to teverse the path. Since the path is controled by the script you need to change the value for the d variable in the function Init

```js
function Init() {
  let w = wrap.clientWidth;
  let h = wrap.clientHeight;
  ellipse.setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", `0 0 ${w}  ${h}`);
  let d = `M${9*w / 10},${h / 2}
  A${4 * w / 10},${4 * h / 10} 0 0 1 ${w / 10} ${5 * h / 10}
  A${4 * w / 10},${4 * h / 10} 0 0 1 ${9 * w / 10} ${5 * h / 10} 
  A${4 * w / 10},${4 * h / 10} 0 0 1 ${w / 10} ${5 * h / 10} 
  A${4 * w / 10},${4 * h / 10} 0 0 1 ${9 * w / 10} ${5 * h / 10} `;

  thePath.setAttributeNS(null, "d", d);
  let path_length =  thePath.getTotalLength();
  
  
  //begin at a bigger size than needed
  let font_size = 100;
  ellipse.style.fontSize = font_size+"px"; 
  
  // while the text length is bigger than half path length 
  while(tp.getComputedTextLength() > path_length / 2 ){
    //reduce the font size
    font_size -=.25;
    //reset the font size 
    ellipse.style.fontSize = font_size+"px";
  }
}



window.setTimeout(function() {
  Init();
  window.addEventListener("resize", Init, false);
}, 15);

let so = 0;

function Marquee() {
  requestAnimationFrame(Marquee);
  tp.setAttributeNS(null, "startOffset", so + "%");
  if (so >= 50) {
    so = 0;
  }
  so += 0.02;
}

Marquee();
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: "Arimo", sans-serif;
}

#wrap{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;  
}
text {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: lighter;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <svg id="ellipse" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
    <path id="thePath" fill="transparent"  />

       <text stroke="black">
          <textPath xlink:href="#thePath" dy="5" id="tp" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs">Coming Soon • Coming Soon • Coming Soon • Coming Soon • Coming Soon • Coming Soon • Coming Soon •</textPath>
        </text>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Also please read the related blog post: https://codepen.io/enxaneta/post/animate-marquee-on-svg-curve

#### UPDATE

the OP is asking;

> Is there anyway to make the svg spin anti clockwise

I'm not very sure what he means by this since the original demo is spinning anticlockwise.
Please try changing the `function Marquee()` like so: instead of increasing the startOffset so you decrease it.

```js
let so = 50;

function Marquee() {
  requestAnimationFrame(Marquee);
  tp.setAttributeNS(null, "startOffset", so + "%");
  if (so <= 0) {
    so = 50;
  }
  so -= 0.02;
}

Marquee();
```

Comment: Thank you very much that helped. Is there anyway to make the svg spin anti clockwise though?

Comment: the demo in codepen you linked to is spinning anticlockwise

Comment: yes. when i added the new lines of code it started spinning clockwise